# Extracting even numbers and doing a function on them with using map function

Tags: python

Does anybody know why below code is OK when the first char of the list is even number but when the first char is odd it is occurred an error??
I know I can improve this code with filter function but I want to know why this error has been occurred

```
def even_nums(num) :
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        return num+1
    return new_list.pop(num)

new_list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,4,32,1] --> OK 
new_list = [5,3,4,5,6,7,4,32,1] --> Error       
print(list(map(even_nums, new_list)))
```

Comment: I get no errors at all when running your code with either test.   HOWEVER, it is VERY bad practice for to modify that list (as a global) while you are iterating through it.  What do you think you are doing?

Comment: Now I see your mistake.  `new_list.pop(num)` does not pop the number "num" from the list.  It pops the num-th element.  If you try to do `pop(32)` when there are only 8 elements, that's an error.  If you are trying to remove all of the odd numbers, you can't do that with `map`.

Comment: What's with that question title? This isn't Twitter.

Comment: @TimRoberts But even if he fixes that, modifying the list while iterating will also cause problems.

Comment: Why the `dictionary` tag? There are no dictionaries in your code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for answering ; you're right and I realized this is a very bad practice. pop method deletes an item according to its index written in (), but this issue will be still appeared if I modify your mentioned problem as Barmar said.

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you for your attention. I've fixed your mentioned faults

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are trying to extract the even numbers from a list, you would do that like this:

```
new_list = [i for i in new_list if i % 2 == 0]
```

**IF** you want what your function was trying to do -- keep only the even numbers but bump them by one -- that would be:

```
new_list = [i+1 for i in new_list if i % 2 == 0]
```

You can't do filtering with `map`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your dedicated time and useful answer but my brain still cope with the issue and its unknown reason I've asked before.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for.  We have pointed out that `pop` is the wrong tool (and why), and we've pointed out that `map` cannot solve this problem.  Those are the reasons.  Don't do it that way.  End of story.

Comment: OK I finished it ;) Thank you for your cooperation again